# "Más me gusta X entonces Y" construction

Tags: modismos

I came across this example sentence on spanishpod101 and just wanted to confirm that this is an actual idiom that is commonly used?

The sentence was:

> Más me gustan las milongas de aquel entonces a los nuevos tangos de hoy.

From which I deduced the pattern "más me gusta X entonces Y" to mean "I much prefer X to Y". I could not find any such use for "entonces" in the dictionary hence my doubt that this could have been an error in the note?

Comment: That site (https://www.spanishpod101.com/lesson/upper-intermediate-19-who-can-resist-the-tango-in-argentina/) is not reliable. It has lots of mistakes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in the sentence. The pattern is "más me gusta X a Y" (meaning, as you have deducted, "I much prefer X to Y"):

> Más me gustan X=(las milongas de aquel entonces) a Y=(los nuevos tangos de hoy).

Note that the sentence is comparing two kind of dances from two different periods of time:

> Los nuevos tangos **de hoy**.
>   Las milongas **de aquel entonces**.

The use of *entonces* must not be separated from *de aquel*, as *de aquel entonces* is an expression that means "from that (period of) time". [Other similar constructions are](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FivP8ug):

- *En aquel entonces*.
- *Por aquel entonces*.

Answer (score 0):

> Más me gustan las milongas de aquel entonces a los nuevos tangos de hoy.

What you didn't realize is that here, **entonces** is a noun.  It means "period [of time]" but with a flavor of nostalgia.

Still, the construction being used, **Más me gusta X a Y**, is a bit unusual.  I see it as a variant of the more common construction

> Prefiero X a Y.

(which is the one I recommend you learn, as a pattern, for expressing your ideas).

Here are a couple of examples taken from linguee.com for this construction:

*Por lo que respecta al espacio, **prefiero** esta oficina **a** la anterior.*

***Prefiero*** la literatura contemporánea **a** la clásica.

Comment: *Más me gusta X a Y* is a bit unusual? I'd say it's outright incorrect!

Comment: @Gustavson - Please see my comment to the new question: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23765/use-of-preposition-a-instead-of-que-in-más-menos-comparisons#comment38704_23765